# Select options taking same value every time

Tags: php

Looping from database duplicating the option values in options tag.

Please help me out.

My code is below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="beautician<?php echo $data[0]; ?>[]" id="beautician">
<select name="beautician[<?php echo $data[0]; ?>]" id="beauty" onchange="pvalue()">
    <option value="null">Select</option>
    <?php
    $query = "select id,title from beautician order by id";
    $run = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
        $id = $row[0];
        $name = $row[1];
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?> </option>                                                         
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

whenever the user is selecting beautician it is taking id of the first option.

If id of the first selected beautician is 6 then every other beautician will have id 6

[image]

Comment: Can you please format your code properly ?

Answer (score 2):

Because you forgot to print `$id`

Correct

```
<option value="<?php $id;  ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?> </option>
```

To

```
<option value="<?php echo $id;  ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?> </option>
```

Comment: @GautamPruthi, please find out what you are returning from database. Also, view source and find out what is getting loaded in drop down.

Answer (score 2):

Instead this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="beautician<?php echo $data[0]; ?>[]" id="beautician">
     <select name="beautician[<?php echo $data[0]; ?>]" id="beauty" onchange="pvalue()">
            <option value="null">Select</option>
            <?php
                $query = "select id,title from beautician order by id";
                $run = mysql_query($query);
                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
                $id = $row[0];
                $name = $row[1];

             ?>
            <option value="<?php $id;  ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?> </option>

            <?php  } ?>
    </select>
```

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="beautician <?php echo $data[0]; ?>[]" id="beautician">
     <select name="beautician[<?php echo $data[0]; ?>]" id="beauty" onchange="pvalue()">
            <option value="null">Select</option>
            <?php
                $query = "select id,title from beautician order by id";
                $run = mysql_query($query);
                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $name = $row['title'];

             ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $id;  ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?> </option>

            <?php  } ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the below statement you are not echoing `$id` in value. To get the value you have to `<?php echo $id;?>` OR `<?=$id?>`. Using your existing statement you have not printed the `$id` so the select option will take the `<option>` tag's text value, In your case value will be from `$name` variable.

Your statement:

```
<option value="<?php $id;  ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?> </option>
```

Correct Statement:

```
<option value="<?php echo $id;  ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?> </option>
```

As per my thinking you are getting value from the `pvalue()` on the change event of `<select>` tag and in this function you might be getting value based on the `#beauty` selector, because of this you are getting first dropdown value this happens because of duplicate id selector `#beauty`

Checkout below fiddle. There are two dropdowns and those have `onchange="pvalue(this)"` function on change event. Instead of no parameters in `pvalue()` function I have passed `this` in `pvalue(this)` function. Based on `this` parameter it will give you current `<select>` option.

```html
<select name="beautician[0]" id="beauty" onchange="pvalue(this)">
    <option value="null">Select</option>
    <option value="one - 1">One - 1</option>
    <option value="Two - 1">Two - 1</option>
</select>
<select name="beautician[1]" id="beauty" onchange="pvalue(this)">
    <option value="null">Select</option>
    <option value="one - 2">One - 2</option>
    <option value="Two - 2">Two - 2</option>
</select>
<script>

function pvalue(obj, rowid){
var x = obj.value;
var y = document.getElementById('beautician'+ ).value = x;
    alert(x);
}
</script>
```

```
<input type="hidden" name="beautician<?php echo $data[0]; ?>[]" id="beautician-<?php echo $data[0]; ?>">
<select name="beautician[<?php echo $data[0]; ?>]" id="beauty" onchange="pvalue(this, '<?php echo $data[0]; ?>')">
    <option value="null">Select</option>
</select>

<script>
    function pvalue(obj, rowid) {
        var x = obj.value;
        var y = document.getElementById('beautician-' + rowid).value = x;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please paste that statement you have changed

Comment: Are you getting values through jquery?

Comment: please help me You can check the whole page source code  from this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PV_PswFqRDMFCczbBkMm2y8d6oFI5zJE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As per my thinking you are getting value from the pvalue() on the change event of <select> tag and in this function you might be getting value based on the #beauty selector, because of this you are getting first dropdown value this happens because of duplicate id selector #beauty

Comment: and if you want I can give you admin access of the original page

Comment: Checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8ukb0fzn/5/ also I have updated the answer

Comment: you can check the code from this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PVqNqy7AUyp7M5o5iqrsr3LjiwP_uc73/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated the answer at the last. added id with unique number in hidden field, pass unique number in `pvalue(this, '<?php echo $data[0]; ?>')` function. Just put the code I have updated in the answer

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<option value="<?php $id;  ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?> </option>
```

Should  be:

```
<option value="<?php echo $id;  ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?> </option>
```